# Bar Chart Diagram Not Populating Excel ( utilizing xlsxwriter )

Tags: python, excel, module, bar-chart, xlsxwriter

Syntax is pushing through however the bar chart that I have created isn't presenting on my excel analysis sheet. I'm using the xlsxwriter module and added the specific dimensions on where the data is presented in my excel sheet. Behind the mechanics: exported 3 csv files to 1 single excel sheet to state a chart on the csv.data.

code:

```
workbook_1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\testdba\\Downloads\\DB_1.xlsx')

worksheet_1 = workbook_1.add_worksheet()

chart1 = workbook_1.add_chart({'type': 'bar', 'subtype':'stacked'})

chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '= sheetname !$I$1:$J$1',
    'categories': '= sheetname !$I$2:$I$5',
    'values':     '= sheetname !$J$2:$J$5',
})


chart1.add_series({
    'name':       ['sheetname', 0, 8, 0, 9],
    'categories': ['sheetname', 1, 8, 4, 8],
    'values':     ['sheetname', 1, 9, 4, 9],
})

chart1.set_title ({'name': 'AGILE COUNT'})

chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'AGILE'})

chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'COUNT'})

chart1.set_style(11)

worksheet_1.insert_chart('K2', chart1)
```

results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Mg8.png)

Data that I'm pulling to state on cell - K2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2gKP.png)

Comment: You understand that xlsxwriter creates xlsx file from new it doesn't edit existing sheets. So your specifying a sheet name of 'sheetname' but when adding the sheet you do no name it as that so it will be 'Sheet1' by default. The add sheet should be **worksheet_1 = workbook_1.add_worksheet('sheetname')** You also need to write the values for I1:J5 into the sheet like you have in the 2nd series for this 1st series.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the spaces in the references to the data on the sheet so you dont get the 'contains spaces' messages;
Change

```
'name':       '= sheetname !$I$1:$J$1',
```

to

```
'name':       '=sheetname!$I$1:$J$1',
```

for each line.

You basically want your code to look like this exmple below;

```
...
workbook_1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\testdba\\Downloads\\DB_1.xlsx')


worksheet_1 = workbook_1.add_worksheet('sheetname')
worksheet_1.write_row('I1', ['AGILE ACRONYM', 'COUNT'])
worksheet_1.write_row('I2', ['CO', 13])
worksheet_1.write_row('I3', ['MCO', 5])
worksheet_1.write_row('I4', ['PER', 4])
worksheet_1.write_row('I5', ['PPI', 0])

chart1 = workbook_1.add_chart({'type': 'bar', 'subtype':'stacked'})

chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=sheetname!$I$1:$J$1',
    'categories': '=sheetname!$I$2:$I$5',
    'values':     '=sheetname!$J$2:$J$5',
})


chart1.add_series({
    'name':       ['sheetname', 0, 8, 0, 9],
    'categories': ['sheetname', 1, 8, 4, 8],
    'values':     ['sheetname', 1, 9, 4, 9],
})

chart1.set_title ({'name': 'AGILE COUNT'})
```